# Showing that $A \cap X = A$ for all $A$ if and only if $X = S$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have the following task:

> Let $S$ be a nonempty set. All capital letters will denote
>   subsets of $S$. Show that $A \cap X = A$ for all $A$ if and only if $X = S$.

This does not seem to true. As motivation consider the following example:
$$ A \subset X \subset S$$

Then $A \cap X  = A$ for all $A$  but $X \neq  A$.

Am I correct by saying that the above proposition is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**.

The statement of the problem is, consider $X \subseteq S$ "fixed".

Then, $A \cap X = A$, for all $A$, **iff** $X=S$.

If $X$ is a "fixed" subset of $S$ such that $X \ne S$, you can always find a subset $A$ of $S$ such that $A \cap X \ne A$.

If $X \ne S$, then there exists $a \in S$ such that $a \notin X$.

Consider $A = \{ a \}$.

Then $A \subseteq S$ but **not** $A \subseteq X$ and, in particular : $A \cap X = \emptyset \ne A$.

Comment: I misread the question. I am an idiot.

Comment: @Matthew - I mean that in your purported *counterexample*, you have assumed to be able to "choose" an $X$ such that $A⊂X⊂S$ **for all** $A$. Thus, in the argument we consider $X$ fixed and show that it is not true that all $A$ must be "included" into $X$. If $X \ne S$ we can always find a not-empty $A$ such that $A \cap X = \emptyset$.

Comment: What if we want to prove the statement because if $ X = S$ and $S$ is all capital letters (from A to Z) would it be something like $ A \cap A...Z$ and the only element we have in common is $A$? I'm talking about the second one which is if $X = S$ then $A \cap X = A$. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @usukidoll - I'm not sure to understand your question. If $X=S$, under the assumption that "all capital letters will denote subsets of S", i.e. $A \subseteq S$, then it is clear that if $X=S$ then $A∩X=A$ for all $A$, because $A \cap X = A \cap S = A$.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to say. Since we know that S is a nonempty set which means there are elements in S. Also we know that S is all of the capital letters from A to Z ( A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)  So, if X = S, and we need to show that $ A \cap X = A$. Then we would have, $A \cap S = A$. Since S is all of the capital letters, then by set intersection definition, the only element in common is A. It's like $ \

Comment: @usukidoll - I thin you have misunderstood the OP's statement; when he write "All capital letters will denote subsets of S" - I think - he is only asserting that, in the ongoing description of the problem, all capital letters ($A,X$) will be used to denote subset of $S$, this in order to avoid the repetition of the clause : "let $A$ a subset of $S$ ...".

Comment: really?  wait so it has nothing to do with capital letters? so A and X being used to denote subset of S would that mean that A and X are elements in S?

Comment: oh wait a second... $A \subseteq S$ means that A is contained in S, so if we have $ X = S$ and substitute that , then $A \subseteq X$ which means that A is contained in X....but then what happens next? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @usukidoll - **YES**. The question is : "Show that $A∩X=A$ for all $A$ if and only if $X=S$ [where $A,X \subseteq S$ - this is the translation of the "capital letetrs" clause].

Comment: @usukidoll - see my answer. *(i)* When $X=S$, clearly if $A \subseteq X$, then $A \cap X = A$ because "all of" $A$ is "inside" $X$. *(ii)* When $A \cap X = A$, **for all** $A \subseteq S$, this means that (prove it formally ...) that **all** subsets of $S$ are included into $X$. But also $S$ itself is an (improper) subset of $S$; thus, the condition inmplies that $X$ coincide with $S$.

Comment: OH! for (i) suppose X = S, then  A is contained in X .... A is inside of X so $ A \cap X =A $ is true because of the "A" is in X, so A and X is equal to A .

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is an alternative proof, based on expanding the definitions and using the laws of logic to simplify.  We'll make all quantifications explicit, to try and avoid misunderstandings.

To reduce notational noise, we will implicitly assume $\;A,X \subseteq S\;$ and $\;x \in S\;$.

We calculate as follows, for all $\;X\;$,

$$\calc
\langle \forall A :: A \cap X = A \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;=\;$ on sets (set extensionality); definition of $\;\cap\;$}
\langle \forall A :: \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \in X \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: merge quantifications; $\;P \land Q \equiv P\;$ and $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$ are alternatives for $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$}
\langle \forall A, x :: x \not\in A \lor x \in X \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: extract the part that does not use $\;A\;$ outside of $\;\forall A\;$}
\langle \forall x :: \langle \forall A :: x \not\in A \rangle \lor x \in X \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{nested quantification is false: take $\;A := \{x\}\;$}
\langle \forall x :: \text{false} \lor x \in X \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify}
\langle \forall x :: x \in X \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, using implicit $\;x \in S\;$}
S \subseteq X
\calcop{\equiv}{using $\;X \subseteq S\;$}
X = S
\endcalc$$